# Calcular totais pai e filho

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Amigos tenho 2 modelos. Orders tem varios details. Uso o cocoon para criar os formulários. O modelo order tem um total que é a soma dos totais dos modelos filhos. O que eu gostaria de saber é qual a melhor maneira de implementar um somatório no filho e depois no pai, do campo total e quantidade, sempre que o modelo for salvo.

campos do modelo order:

```
t.string   "customer_id"
t.decimal  "valor_total"
t.integer  "item_total"
t.string   "order_num"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

campos do modelo detail:

```
t.string   "order_id"
t.string   "cod_produto"
t.string   "desc_produto"
t.string   "cod_cor"
t.string   "desc_cor"
t.string   "desc_tamanho"
t.decimal  "preco"
t.integer  "quantidade"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.float    "total"
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :details, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :customer
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :details, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
   validates :customer_id,
             :presence => true
end
```

detail.rb

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Pessoal problema resolvido. Os modelos ficaram assim:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :details, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :customer
accepts_nested_attributes_for :details, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
validates :customer_id,
        :presence => true
before_save :sum_details
private
  def sum_details
   self.valor_total = self.details.inject(0){|sum,detail| sum +   detail.total }
  end
end

class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
before_save :sum_prices
   private
   def sum_prices
     self.total = self.preco*self.quantidade 
   end
end
```

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Faz o seguinte, no modelo detail.rb, deixe-o assim:

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order
   before_save :sum_prices

   private 
   def sum_prices
     self.total = self.preco*self.quantidade
     self.save!
   end

end
```

No order.rb deixe assim:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :details, dependent: :destroy
   belongs_to :customer
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :details, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
   validates :customer_id,
             :presence => true
   before_save :sum_details


   private
   def sum_details
     total = 0
     self.details each do |d|
      total += d.total
     end
     self.valor_total = total
     self.save!
   end
end
```

Comment: Mauricio está dando erro : SystemStackError in OrdersController#update
stack level too deep. Ele nao deveria antes fazer o somatorio dos filhos e depois o do pai ?

Answer (score 0):

Da pra deixar um pouco mais conciso o metodo sum_details.

```
def sum_detail
  self.valor_total = self.details.inject(0){|sum,detail| sum + detail.total }
end
```

Retira o self.save! de sum_prices e de sum_details.

Comment: Boa ideia. Mas o erro mencionado acima continua dando.

Comment: Vilmar, você podia unificar outras 2 respostas somente nesta. Não parece que são soluções distintas. Se a intenção foi comentar na outra resposta, não use o campo de responder para comentários. Quando atingir 50 de reputação, poderá comentar em qualquer pergunta :)

Comment: Para deixar um pouco mais conciso:

self.details.map(&:total).reduce(:+)